# Translate php regex to java

Tags: java, regex

I have trouble to translate this php regex `/^([-\.\w]+)$/` to java regex.

I try `^([-\\.\\w]+)$` but don't work.

The regex is used to validate a string used for a name of file.

in PHP is not allowed `têst.ext`, but in JAVA it's.

Comment: can you define **but don't work** can you share some inputs that not works ok please

Comment: Why doesn't it work? What is your input? Which method are you using? Please post a [MCVE]

Comment: The error is no in the input, the error is in the regex java syntax, the question is Why its happening only in it? I write wrong or PHP and JAVA have different manipulation?

Answer (score 2):

In java, it would be:

```
str.matches("[-.\\w]+")
```

- There is no need to escape the dot in a character class in *any* language/tool.
- There is no need to use `^` or `$` with java's `String#matches()` because it's implied (the *whole* string must match)
- There is no need to create a group (the brackets)

Comment: There's no need for them, but they shouldn't cause it to fail, should it?